# Is there a special name for a normal subgroup which defines a split extension?

Tags: group-theory, terminology

If $G$ is a group and $N$ is its normal subgroup then $G$ is the extension of $G/N$ by $N$. The elements of $G/N$ are the equivalence classes of $G$ of the equivalence relation $g\equiv h$ defined as "*there is a $n\in N$ so, that $h=ng$*". In some cases there is a choice of the representatives of the equivalence classes which form a supgroup of $G$. In this case we say that $G$ is a *split extension* of $G/N$ by N, or, equivalently, that $G$ splits over $N$. So, generally, a normal subgroup defines a group extension, and in some cases this extension is a split extension. Is there a special name for these special normal subgroups? (e.g. *split subgroup* or *splitting subgroup*)

Comment: I don't think that there is a completely standard expression for this, but you could call it a complemented normal subgroup.

Comment: Some authors do call them "splitting subgroups", see [Loth Direct decompositions of LCA groups](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-0348-7591-2_24). [PlanetMath](https://planetmath.org/SemidirectFactorAndQuotientGroup) calls them "semi-direct factors" since the group is a semi-direct product of this subgroup and the quotient by it. "Complemented normal subgroup" is [also used](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Complemented_normal_subgroup). Related [When does a subgroup H of a group G have a complement in G?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/5528/51484) on MO.

Comment: I'd say "split/complemented normal subgroup", explicitly emphasizing normal. I don't like "splitting", which conveys the intuition that the normal subgroup "produces" its complement.